# How do I append a / (forward slash) to a URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am working on an Expression Engine site and the URLs end as follows:

> http://www.example.com/education/new-courses

I need to be able append a forward slash after just this one link, so that it looks like this:

> http://www.example.com/education/new-courses/

I am looking for an appropriate ReWrite rule that would add the necessary `/`. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a rewrite rule or something else?

Comment: Yes. I believe that is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really mean just this one URL?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^education/new-courses$ /education/new-courses/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Matchu, yes that is the one I want to change. It doesn't seem to work though. The URL still shows without the trailing slash.

BTW - UP was a great movie.

Comment: Make sure you have the Rewrite Engine enabled - I'll add that line. Yes, it was :D

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you may need to check your server configuration. If you're on a shared host, this method may be disabled entirely.

Comment: Brilliant. I just had to move it up in the hierarchy and it works great. Thank you.